# Typeorm find() method, select nested column (type object) of a nested in a leftJoined, leftJoined relation

Tags: node.js, typescript, typeorm

I would like to end selecting workoutPlan, workouts and workout.thumbnail.content so that, for every workoutPlan i have his nested array of workouts and each of them joins the thumbnail but selects only the content field of the thumbnail (thumbnail.content)

```js
export class WorkoutPlanEntity {

  ............
  
  @ManyToMany(() => WorkoutEntity, workout => workout.workoutPlans)
    workouts: WorkoutEntity[];
    
}
```

```js
export class WorkoutEntity {

  .........
  
  @Column({ nullable: true })
    @IsUUID()
    @IsOptional()
    thumbnail_uuid: string;
   
  @ManyToOne(() => ThumbnailEntity, thumbnail => thumbnail.workouts)
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'thumbnail_uuid', referencedColumnName: 'uuid' })
    thumbnail: ThumbnailEntity;
    
}
```

```js
export class ThumbnailEntity {

  .............
   @Column({ type: 'json' })
   @IsObject()
   content: object;
}
```

```js
 const [find, total] = await this.workoutPlans.findAndCount({
            relations: ['workouts', 'workouts.thumbnail'],
            order: { workouts: { workoutPlanWorkouts: { order: 'asc' } } },
            skip: skip,
            take: take,
            select: ['workouts', 'workouts'],
        });
```

[image: typescript error given by my query]

I tried many things, using queryBuilder aswell but queryBuilder ends up making mistakes on the generated SQL query when using orderBy leftJoin and skip/take